# Iterative Insertion Reverse Search

Tags: python, search, insert, iteration, reverse

I have a code that iteratively inserts itself at user specified positions. It gives a long string as a result of the iteration. What I need is to do the reverse. Writing a code that takes a string and uses iteration to find out what the inital string was and the insertion positions.

```
def iterative_insertion(S, positions):
    R = S

    for pos in positions:
        if 0 <= pos <= len(R):
            R = R[:pos] + R + R[pos:]

    return R

# Example usage
S = "abcd"
positions = [0, 1, 1, 13]
result = iterative_insertion(S, positions)
expected = "aaabcdabcdbcdaaabcdabcdbcdabcdabcdabcdbcdabcdabcdabcdabcdbcdabcd"

print("Expected: ", expected)
print("Result: ", result)
print("Match: ", result == expected)
print("Lengths: ", len(result), len(S), len(expected))
```

I need a function that will take the input of "aaabcdabcdbcdaaabcdabcdbcdabcdabcdabcdbcdabcdabcdabcdabcdbcdabcd" and use iteration to find the inital string and the insertion positions.

In other words, the output would be

```
Inital string = "abcd"
positions = [0, 1, 1, 13]
```

Here is what I have

```
def reverse_iterative_insertion(s):
    initial_string = ""
    positions = []
    current_position = 0

    for char in s:
        if char not in initial_string:
            initial_string += char
        else:
            current_position = initial_string.index(char)
            positions.append(current_position)
            initial_string = initial_string[:current_position] + char + initial_string[current_position:]

    return initial_string, positions

# Example usage
input_string = "aaabcdabcdbcdaaabcdabcdbcdabcdabcdabcdbcdabcdabcdabcdabcdbcdabcd"
initial, insert_positions = reverse_iterative_insertion(input_string)

print("Initial string:", initial)
print("Insertion positions:", insert_positions)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it possible to differentiate ab from abab?

Comment: Yes, since it uses iteration to find the output. @RuslanNakibov

Comment: What is your question/problem?

Comment: @RuslanNakibov `"ab"` with positions `[0, 0]` produces the same as `"abab"` with `[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive function could do this nicely:

```
def uninsert(R):
    for p in range(len(R) // 2 + 1):
        e = p + len(R) // 2
        if R[p:e] == R[:p] + R[e:]:
            S, P = uninsert(R[p:e])
            return S, P + [p]      
    return R, []

print(*uninsert(expected)) 
              
abcd [0, 1, 1, 13]
```

Given that each insertion doubles the size of the string, the function checks for a match between a substring of half the length with the rest of the string (on its left and right).  The substring can only start from the left half of the resulting string so only those positions are checked.

*Note that there could be multiple solutions in the reversal so the result may be different from the original positions.  For example, if your original string already had the pattern of an iterative insertion, there would be more positions in the uninsert result (unless you know the number of expected positions which you could then use as an additional constraint).*

```
S         = "abab"
positions = [0, 1, 1, 13]
result    = iterative_insertion(S, positions)

print(*uninsert(result))   
            
ab [0, 0, 1, 1, 13]
```

Comment: Nice, looks very clean! +1 :)

Comment: Looks good. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the question just wants to find a pattern that exists in a string.

so this (or a similar variant) would work.

```py
input_string = "aaabcdabcdbcdaaabcdabcdbcdabcdabcdabcdbcdabcdabcdabcdabcdbcdabcd"

pattern = "abcd"

matches = []
start_idx = 0
while True:
    idx = input_string.find(pattern, start_idx)
    if idx == -1:
        break
    matches.append(idx)
    start_idx = idx + 1

print(matches)
```

which returns this (for the example given):

```
[2, 6, 15, 19, 26, 30, 34, 41, 45, 49, 53, 60]
```

Comment: The problem is, you don't know the `pattern`, you must figure it out from the `input_string` (If I understand OP correctly.)

Comment: @AndrejKesely,  if that is the case, then the question is unsolvable in the case where the pattern was inserted just on time...  but you could be right.

Comment: That is correct @AndrejKesely

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
s = "aaabcdabcdbcdaaabcdabcdbcdabcdabcdabcdbcdabcdabcdabcdabcdbcdabcd"

out, current = [], len(s) // 2

while True:
    for i in range(len(s) - current):
        left, center, right = s[:i], s[i : i + current], s[i + current :]

        if left + right == center:
            out.append(i)
            s, current = center, len(center) // 2
            break
    else:
        break

print(out[::-1], s)
```

Pritns:

```
[0, 1, 1, 13] abcd
```

Comment: @SJBrigante Do you mean to wrap it into a funcion? You can do it but instead of `print` just return the required output.